# Best practice for packaging modules with sub-modules - most using the same libraries

Tags: python, package, software-distribution

I am currently packaging my own module for distribution. In general everything is working fine, but fine-tuning/best-practice for structuring sub-modules is giving me some trouble.

Assuming a module structure of:

```
mdl
├── mdl
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
|   ├── sub_one
|   |   ├── __init__.py
|   |   └── core_sub_one.py
|   └── sub_two
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── core_sub_two.py
├── README
└── setup.py
```

---

### core file headers

With the **header of `core.py`** starting with:

```
import numpy as np

...some fairly large module code...
```

And the **headers of both `core_sub_one.py` and `core_sub_two.py`** starting with:

```
import numpy as np

from .. import core as cr
```

So **all submodules require `np` and `cr`.**

---

### **init**.py structure

The **`mdl/__init__.py`** (core-level) looks like:

```
from . import sub_one as so
from . import sub_two as st
```

And **`__init__.py` of both submodules** looks like (replace `one` with `two` for the other submodule):

```
from . import core_sub_one
from .core_sub_one import *
```

I've "learnt" this structure from `numpy`, see f.i. [`numpy/ma/__init__.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/__init__.py)

---

### Problem description

Now I've got some trouble with the submodule-access after running `setup.py` and importing my module with `import mdl`.
I can now access my submodules with f.i. `mdl.so.some_function_in_sub_one()`. This is expected and what I want.

**But** I can also access the top level module `cr` **and** `numpy` with `mdl.so.cr` and `mdl.so.np`, **which I want to avoid.** Is there any way to avoid this?
If not: Is there any drawback of importing/connecting modules and submodules like this?

**And** is there any best practice for how to import libraries like `numpy` in sub-modules, when they are required in **all** submodules?

**Edit:**
Since some seem to have trouble with the fact that asking for *best practice* is *opinion based* (which I know and which I intended, since imho most design decisions in real life are not clear binary 1-0 decisions), I have to add:
I want to comply with the module packaging style used in the `scipy`, and more specifically `numpy`, package environment. So if these packages found a solution for any of the questions I asked, this will be the most welcome solution for me.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted and closed? It has a clear layout and problem description. Also the questions are quite straight-forward. And **of course** a question asking for "best practice" is opinion based. That's exactly what "best practice" implies... In most cases in real life there is just no I/O decision... Since SO often receives the feedback of not being *user friendly*: Exactly this downvoting/closing behaviour is the reason for it. Just let a more or less well posed question stand for itself and let the community "live" instead of suffocating it with frustrating behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first:

> from .core_sub_one import *

DONT DO THIS. Yes, even if you seen it in some "big name" package, read it in some tutorials or whatever. This is [officially considered bad practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), and for good reasons (from experience, it's a maintaince hell).

If you really really insist on doing this (but seriously, don't), at least [define an explicit `__all__` var in those modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) so you keep exposed names under control (and it helps documenting what's supposed to be part of the module's API).

> But I can also access the top level module cr and numpy with mdl.so.cr and mdl.so.np, which I want to avoid. Is there any way to avoid this?

Not really. If you're really worried about it, you can import those names as "protected" in your submodules:

```
# core_sub_xxx.py

import numpy as _np
from .. import core as _cr
```

(of course you'll have to replace all occurrences of 'np' and 'cr' but any half-decent text editor can do this)

This doesn't prevent access to `mysubmodule._cr` or `mysubmodule._np` but at least it makes it clear that one should NOT access those names.

But really, this is not a big issue, as long as your API is clearly documented.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Considering the first point: Yeah, I **never** use starred imports to avoid conflicts with duplicate method, class etc. names. But as you said: With numpy, it is in one of the "big(gest?) name" packages and so I thought, it may be ok in *this special* case. Thanks for clarification! Second point: For numpy it is imho reasonably acceptable to use `np`, but for `cr` I'll take your private import approach. Thansk again! Also I'll take a lookt at the `__all__` var.